# How to convert json object to custom type before deserializing?

Tags: c#, json

I have a class:

```
public class LineItemWithDetails
{
        public LineItem LineItem { get; set; }
        public object Details { get; set; }

}
```

And a webservice method that takes in a json object passed in from javascript, and deserializes it:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public string SaveLineItemDetails(object details, int categoryId, int lineItemId)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    LineItemWithDetails lineItem = serializer.Deserialize<LineItemWithDetails>(details.ToString());

}
```

The parameter "details", looks like this:
details.Details["Name"] = "tessa";
details.Details["PositionTitle"] = "whatever";

My question is, I want the Details property in the LineItemDetails class to be converted to BudgetPersonnel (see below) before deserializing so that the values from the json object are assigned to BudgetPersonnel properties. BudgetPersonnel is just an example of one type, there are several others. The one to convert to is determined by the categoryId parameter in the webservice method. I have been through so many tutorials about generic casting, and they work. However, I don't understand how to make this happen before deserializing. The code listed above in SaveLineItemDetails deserializes, but the Details property is obviously just an object, and not of BudgetPersonnel type.

Example:

```
public BudgetPersonnel(string name, string positionTitle)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.PositionTitle = positionTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not quite sure i get your problem so here is my shot at an answer.

So what you want basicly is some JSON being deserialized into a BudgetPersonnel object?
I had a similar problem when I was doing an assignment for school that involved a call to a server, and the server returning a JSON string. I used a library that serialized every sort of object as long as the JSON string contained something like this:

```
"class":"MyClass"
```

I guess this is want you? A JSON string converted into a certain object with the assigned values? I would recommend using an existing library to do that ([Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSON.html) for example)
And just pass on a JSON string looking something like this:

```
["Name":"tessa" , "PositionTitle":"superman"]
```

I hope it helped, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think that my problem is more of trying to figure out how to cast or convert the Details parameter in LineItemDetails to my custom type before deserializing. BudgetPersonnel is just one type of several that I have, that are passed in as categoryId to the webservice method. I updated my question a little to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: How can you cast an object that has not been de-serialized? A solution is to de-serialize the JSON string in to the type "that best fits" and then perform casting. As I suggested in my answer, writing your own de-serialization code would more efficient and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own de-serialization class that implements abstract base class JavaScriptConverter.

Taken from MSDN:

```
serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// Register the custom converter.
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { 
    new System.Web.Script.Serialization.CS.ListItemCollectionConverter() });
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx