# Facing deserialization issue due to double quotes in data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am calling a service and getting data like  :-

```
var httpResponse = request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>();
```

I am facing deserialization issue because response contains data like below, data has double quotes :-

```
"name": "short_nme/"kfc"",
"count": "4",
"id": ""kfc""
```

My question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109464/json-net-deserilization-with-double-quotes) because in this question the issue is serialization,mine is deserialization issues

Comment: The "right" solution in this case is a big club on the head of the programmer that created the service :-)

Comment: Well that's just not valid JSON. Talk to whoever is producing the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109464/json-net-deserilization-with-double-quotes appears to cover this question

Comment: quick solution on your end would be to replace "" with " on the whole string, but they do need to send valid json.

Comment: The service is broken, and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @FilixMogilevsky this would work so long as none of the properties are empty, eg: `{ "name": "" }`; @F11: as others have mentioned the service needs to be fixed. Looks like whoever implemented it is manually creating the JSON data by naively concatenating strings instead of using a serializer...

Comment: @flix Wouldn't work. Look at `/"kfc`. They didn't simply "double" the doublequotes (like you do in SQL). They simply didn't escape them.

Comment: thanks guys for pointing me in right direction.I am not closing the question because i think comments might be helpful.