# Map JSON object to C# class property array

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net, mapping, automapper

JSON

```
{
"SoftHoldIDs": 444,
"AppliedUsages": [
    {
        "SoftHoldID": 444,
        "UsageYearID": 223232,
        "DaysApplied": 0,
        "PointsApplied": 1
    }
],
"Guests": [
    1,
    2
]
```

}
In the above JSON SoftholdIDs is integer and AppliedUsages is class array property in C# Model

Issue is --How we can map JSON to class property.
Class code

```
  public class ReservationDraftRequestDto
{

    public int SoftHoldIDs { get; set; }
    public int[] Guests { get; set; }
    public AppliedUsage[] AppliedUsages { get; set; }

}


public class AppliedUsage
{
    public int SoftHoldID { get; set; }
    public int UsageYearID { get; set; }
    public int DaysApplied { get; set; }
    public int PointsApplied { get; set; }
}
```

Tried below code for mapping

```
ReservationDraftRequestDto reservationDto = null;

        dynamic data  = await reservationDraftRequestDto.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                    reservationDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReservationDraftRequestDto>(data.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
         class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{""SoftHoldIDs"": 444,""AppliedUsages"": [    {""SoftHoldID"": 444,""UsageYearID"": 223232,""DaysApplied"": 0,""PointsApplied"": 1}],""Guests"": [ 1, 2]}";

            Rootobject reservationDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json.ToString());

            Debug.WriteLine(reservationDto.SoftHoldIDs);
            foreach (var guest in reservationDto.Guests)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(guest);
            }

        }
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public int SoftHoldIDs { get; set; }
        public Appliedusage[] AppliedUsages { get; set; }
        public int[] Guests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Appliedusage
    {
        public int SoftHoldID { get; set; }
        public int UsageYearID { get; set; }
        public int DaysApplied { get; set; }
        public int PointsApplied { get; set; }
    }


}
```

First create class copying json as classwith visualstudio.
Next you have double quote  in json respons so deal with it.
[Json.NET: Deserilization with Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109464/json-net-deserilization-with-double-quotes)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
dynamic data  = await reservationDraftRequestDto.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
```

to

```
string data = await reservationDraftRequestDto.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

this will read your response as string

then do

```
reservationDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReservationDraftRequestDto>(data);
```

Comment: not working---Getting error  Exception while executing function:
 Function1. Newtonsoft.Json: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
 into type 'testazfunction.AppliedUsage' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
 JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Try changing public int[] Guests { get; set; } to public List<int> Guests { get; set; } and public AppliedUsage[] AppliedUsages { get; set; } to public List<AppliedUsage> AppliedUsages { get; set; } in your DTO's

Comment: Have you checked the actual json that is coming from the server, maybe it is malformed?