# Deserialize JSON Object to C# Object Mapping

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a JSON object returned from API with the below format:

```
{
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "responseDetails": {
        "limit": 1000,
        "offset": 0,
        "size": 2,
        "total": 2
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "tbl.col": "data"
        },
        {
            "tbl.col": "data"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to map the above JSON object "data" to a class or to generic type list

Comment: please...1) search for an existing answer, 2) post what you have tried.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364283/map-json-object-to-c-sharp-class-property-array

Comment: Please provide any sample code not only your JSON result

Comment: If you're woriied about the dot in `tbl.col` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376524/accessing-properties-with-a-dot-in-their-name/36377225#36377225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is like this...

First your model has to be like this:

```
    public class ResponseModel
    {
      public string responseStatus { get; set; }
      public ResponseDetail responseDetails { get; set; }

      public List<DataModel> data = new List<DataModel>();
    }
    public class ResponseDetail
    {
      public int limit { get; set; }
      public int offset { get; set; }
      public int size { get; set; }
      public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataModel
    {
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tbl.col")]
      public string tbl_col { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you need to call:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(inputJSONStringGoesHere);
```

You will need to add Newtonsoft JSON nuget package for this to work.

Also the attribute

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tbl.col")]
```

is used in the sample code because C# does not allow "." (dots) in member names.